# Retrieving Secret from Azure Key Vault: Task<string> or regular string?

Tags: azure-keyvault

I have two ways of retrieving secrets from my vault. One is async while the other is not.

Async:

```
public static async Task<string> GetSecret(string secretName)
    {
        try
        {
            return (await GetClient().GetSecretAsync("VaultURL", secretName)).Value;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Not async:

```
      public static string GetSecretWithoutAwait(string SecretName)
    {
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
        return keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("vaultUrl", SecretName).Result.Value;
    }
```

Not having an async method suits my needs the most, and I prefer to keep it that way if possible. What are the consequences to making the retrieval a non-async process?

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the consequences to making the retrieval a non-async process?

The [`Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html) member only exists on the `Task<T>` type; it does not exist on the `Task` type.

Like Wait, Result will synchronously block the calling thread until the task completes. This is generally not a good idea for the same reason it wasn’t a good idea for Wait: **it’s easy to cause deadlocks**.

If you have to block waiting the completion of an `Async` Task, use [`GetAwaiter().GetResult()`](https://medium.com/@deep_blue_day/long-story-short-async-await-best-practices-in-net-1f39d7d84050). `Wait` and `Result` will wrap any exceptions within an `AggregateException`, which complicates error handling. The advantage of `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is that it returns a normal exception instead of an `AggregateException`.

So I suggest that you use Async method to retrieve secrets